# Going back to the history of my working directory - git, bash

Tags: linux, git, bash

I used git commit command directly on a remote repo, then git reseting hard to HEAD^,and I don't know which files of the remote directory were deleted, is possible to find the history of the files of my remote **working directory** ? Perhaps a bash command would suffice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view what files were deleted with:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --summary | grep delete
```